# Krypton Toolkit controls not showing in form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, krypton-toolkit

Krypton used to be a purchase item, but now it's displayed on Github for personal and commercial projects.

https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and the components seems to work in this version as I quote:

> Full source code for all the controls and components is included along
>   with Visual Studio project and solution files for 2005, 2008 and 2010
>   versions of Visual Studio. If you are using a newer version of Visual
>   Studio you can still load the solutions and it will compile just fine.

I have download the github files and I have a bunch of dll files. I have added those dll files into my Visual Studio Toolbox.

What happens is that the items are added successfull but when I drag and drop them into the form they do not appear. I have tried the Buttons, DataGridViews, etc, none of them work.

[image]

The project shows no error when I run..what am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Solved**.

1) Inherit the KryptonForm

```
public partial class Form1 : KryptonForm
```

2) Add the Design.dll library as reference and not as Toolbox item

Comment: In Visual Basic Inherits should be changed in the *.designer.vb* file:
"Partial Class Form1 Inherits ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm". And both *ComponentFactory.Krypton.Design.dll* and *ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll* needs to be added as reference.

Comment: Do i need to also ship the design dll with the application?

Comment: @Smith yes you do

Comment: i disagree with that after making further research online

Comment: @Smith 3 years later... do you have any further details on what you have found?  My problem is slightly different in that none of the controls are showing at runtime

Comment: @JustinGreywolf I have never experienced that. Nut do they appear at design-time on the form?

Comment: @Smith - I created a brand new solution, then installed the 65.22.4.94 version of the packages and it worked fine. For some reason it wasnt working with the .152 version